# JavaFX bad logs - Invocation Target Exception

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

Everytime I have an error related to my views (FXML) and controller actions, it ends up showing as a Invocation Target Exception.

e.g.:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
file:/C:/Users/Renato%20Correa/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PartyRock/dist/run32339290/PartyRock.jar!/gear7/partyrock/view/IncluirConvidado.fxml
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2186)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2744)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2709)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2696)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
  at gear7.partyrock.view.IncluirConvidadoView.<init>(IncluirConvidadoView.java:20)
  at gear7.partyrock.controller.IncluirConvidadoController.<init>(IncluirConvidadoController.java:84)
  at gear7.partyrock.controller.ListaConvidadosController.onBtnAddConvidadoClick(ListaConvidadosController.java:94)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:55)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:269)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1435)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
14044 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG gear7.partyrock.view.MainView  - Erro: javafx.fxml.LoadException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
  at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6863)
  at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
  at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
  at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3328)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3168)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3123)
  at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)
  at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2265)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This is too hard to debug. In fact, I can't trace down this error and been struggling with it for the past couple of hours.  What am I doing wrong? How can I trap better the errors in JavaFX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caused by invoking a method via reflection.

```
public static Throwable shortThrowable(Throwable ex) {
    return ex instanceOf InvocationTargetException? ex.getCause() : ex;
}

...
catch (Exception ex) {
    shortThrowable(ex).printStackTrace(); // Or better logging.
}
```

InvokeTargetException wraps any original Exception in a InvocationTargetException.

Comment: Thank you. It clarified a bit. I can now see the actual cause, but still I need to work on a better way of trapping and logging these errors :)

Comment: but where i need to put this method?

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil somewhere you need to catch the exception yourself. Seeing the stacktrace, in gear7.partyrock.view.MainView around line 14044. The method could be imported from a utitlity class into MainView.