# How to get sql exception from InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, jpa, reflection, exception

We are using Apache's openJPA. I am calling a delete method in a managed bean using Java reflection. The problem occurs when I try to delete a manged object that cannot be deleted because of a constraint violation. When I catch the InvocationTargetException and I retrieve the cause of the exception it states that no global transaction existence to roll back.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Global Transaction exists to rollback.
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.UserTransactionImpl.rollback(UserTransactionImpl.java:349)
```

If I look farther down the stack trace I can see that a SQL exception was thrown because of a constraint violation.

```
---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0532] Delete prevented by referential constraint CONSTRAINTNAME in LIBRARY.
```

Is there a way for me to get to the SQL exception so I can display a friendly message that the delete can not be performed because it is in use in another table.

EDIT - Here is the code

```
public void deleteRowAction(Object list, DataTableTemplate template){
        System.out.println("Delete Row");

        try{

            Object bean = getManagedBean(template.getDataManagerName());

            Method methodDelete = getManagedBean(template.getDataManagerName()).getClass().getMethod(template.getDeleteMethod(), 
                    Class.forName(template.getTableList_rowItemClassName()));

            //Map<String, String[]> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterValuesMap();

            methodDelete.invoke(bean, list);
        }
        catch(PersistenceException pe){
            System.out.println("Persistence Exception Caught");
        }
        catch(NoSuchMethodException nsme){
            nsme.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(InvocationTargetException ite){

            logException(ite);
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(ite.getCause().getMessage());
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            FacesContext context = this.getFacesContext();
            context.addMessage(null, message);
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException iae){
            iae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279050/javafx-bad-logs-invocation-target-exception

Comment: add tray catch (SQLException) block around the code which throws exception before the rollback ocures. Probablly in your dao object. Also you could post some code or description how are you calling the delete method.

Comment: My problem is I cannot modify the dao object where the rollback occurs. I posted the code where I call the delete method.

Comment: Thanks Joop Eggan, but the problem is that the getCause() does not get me the constraint error but a rollback error. I am trying to get to the SQL constraint error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using IBM's Websphere. The following code is generated automatically by Websphere. Since a delete did not occur because of the data constraint the rollback failed. This causes the rollback to throw an exception which causes the original exception to be lost. I would have to modify this method if I want to see the Constraint exception (which we cannot do). We are going to log a generic error message instead.

```
 @Action(Action.ACTION_TYPE.DELETE)
 public String deleteVerificationDocumentCodeTable(
                VerificationDocumentCodeTable verificationDocumentCodeTable)
                throws Exception {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
                try {
                    utx.begin();
                    em.joinTransaction();
                    verificationDocumentCodeTable = em
                            .merge(verificationDocumentCodeTable);
                    em.remove(verificationDocumentCodeTable);
                    utx.commit();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    try {
                        utx.rollback();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        throw e;
                    }
                    throw ex;
                } finally {
                    em.close();
                }
                return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your exception into below method, retrieve `SQLException` recursively.

```
    try{
        ....
    } catch(PersistenceException pe){
        SQLException sqle = translate(pe);
    } catch(NoSuchMethodException nsme){
        SQLException sqle = translate(nsme);
    }
    ...

public SQLException translate(RuntimeException e) {
    SQLException result = null;
    Throwable throwable = e;
    while (throwable != null && !(throwable instanceof SQLException)) {
        throwable = throwable.getCause();
    }
    if (throwable instanceof SQLException) {
        System.out.println("Found SQLException...")
        result = (SQLException) throwable;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. Only one cause comes back the No Global Transaction exists to rollback exception. When I try to get the cause on that exception a null is returned.

Comment: @Doug, if so, there is no `SQLException` wrapped by in your transaction. if `PersistenceException ` is thrown, you can retrieve the `SQLException`.

Comment: I did try and catch the PersistenceException but it was not there either. I think I figured out what was going on and posted an answer. If it does not seem right please let me know. Thanks for your help.